# Why do the normally closed and normally open relay contacts have different current ratings?

Tags: current, switches, relay, current-rating

Please refer to the image below:

[image]

Taken from the datasheet:
http://www.songchuan.com/db/pictures/AdminModules/PDT/PDT090410001/201191913495127935.pdf

Comment: There is an asymmetry between the operating force and speed (provided by the solenoid) and the release force and speed (provided by a spring).  A solenoid is strongest when the airgap is 0 so if it's strong enough to overcome the spring and start pulling in, it's MUCH stronger than the spring when it's closed. That gives a higher current rating when closed by the solenoid, i.e. for a NO contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normally close contact is held by the spring pressure. The normally open contact is closed by the coil, which is stronger (and does not wear out with time as a simple spring). 
Contact pressure in turn varies the contact resistance (hence the different ratings). See here for more information:

http://www.willow.co.uk/html/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/Catalogues/pdfs/W_Durakool-Contact-Versus-Pressure-Information.pdf